# Return several arrays from an method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am a beginner at java, but I'm trying to learn.
This is my program i am working on, the user will enter some values, where the program sort all the even values of the index to be the variable radie and all the odd values of the index to be height no matter what the element is. Same goes for nominator och denominator in the next method. But now i am stuck and dont know how to return the arrayList. I want to return my new arrays so i can use them in my other methods. Like i said im very new at java but find it fun to work with but now i need your help. As you can see i have been using swedish words for the outprint, sorry for that.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class program 
{
 private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  
  System.out.println("-------------------------------");
  System.out.println("# Test av area- och volymmetod.");
  System.out.println("-------------------------------");
  double result1 = area1(radie);
  double result2 = area2(radie, height);
  double result3 = volumeCone(radie, height);
  System.out.println("Radie = " + radie + "\tHeight = " + height);
  System.out.printf("Basytans area:%11.2f", result1);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.printf("Mantelytans area:%8.2f", result2);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.printf("Volym:%19.2f", result3);
  System.out.println();
 }
 public static ArrayList<Integer> readFirstInputs(int numberOfInputs)
 {
     System.out.println("Please enter values, Q to quit:");
     int[] inputs = new int[numberOfInputs];
     ArrayList<Integer> radie = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     ArrayList<Integer> height = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
     {
         inputs[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

         if (i % 2 == 0)
         {
             radie.add(inputs[i]);
         }
         else if (i % 2 != 0)
         {
             height.add(inputs[i]);
         }
     }
     return ????? // return radie and height array, how?
 }
 public static ArrayList<Integer> readSecondInputs(int numberOfInputs)
 {
     System.out.println("Please enter values, Q to quit:");
     int[] inputs = new int[numberOfInputs];
     ArrayList<Integer> nominator = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     ArrayList<Integer> denominator = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
     {
         inputs[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

         if (i % 2 == 0)
         {
             nominator.add(inputs[i]);
         }
         else if (i % 2 != 0)
         {
             denominator.add(inputs[i]);
         }
     }
     return ????; // return nominator and denominator array, how?
 }
    /* Use my different arrays in the methods below. */
 public static double area1(int radie) 
 {
  double areaBas = Math.PI * Math.pow(radie, 2);
  return areaBas;
 }
 public static double area2(int radie, int height)
 {
  double areaMantel = Math.PI * radie * Math.sqrt((Math.pow(radie, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2)));
  return areaMantel;
 }
 public static double volumeCone(int radie, int height)
 {
  double volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(radie, 2) * height / 3;
  return volume;
 }
 public static int fractionToInteger(int nominator, int denominator)
 {
  int amount = nominator / denominator;
  return amount;
 }
 public static int fractionToFraction(int nominator, int denominator)
 {
  int remainingAmount = nominator % denominator;
  return remainingAmount;
 }
}
```

Comment: It seems your snippet declares that your code is Javascript

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to do? I'm unsure what your question is asking.

Comment: What is `even`, what is `odd` and why are you returning them individually if you want to return `inputs`. This code makes no sense.

Comment: 1. You can't do `inputs[i] = even;`, inputs is an int array and is expecting ints, doing `inputs[i] = even;` will throw an error since it expects a variable called `even` of type int.  2. If you want seperate arrays that hold the even and odd indexes you need to make them, for example `int[] evenArray = new int[numberOfInputs];`

Comment: Lets say a user enter 10 numbers {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, from this i want to get an new array where {1,3,5,7,9} is one array and {2,4,6,8,10} is the other array. It does not matter which value the user puts in, whats matter is which position it is in the array. So i want to collect all the even indexes and odd indexes in the array.

Comment: You could return an array of arrays.

Comment: `Lets say a user enter 10 numbers…` Do not comment comments asking for clarification or additional information: edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowed to use a list instead? it's way more efficient since once created, you can't change the size of an array, but if you instead create two empty lists you can just use the .add method that lists have, looking similar to this:

```
public static List<Integer> readFirstInputs(int numberOfInputs)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter values, Q to quit:");
    int[] inputs = new int[numberOfInputs];
    List<Integer> evens = new List<Integer>();
    List<Integer> odds = new List<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    {
        inputs[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            evens.add(inputs[i]);
        }
        else if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            odds.add(inputs[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

of course I am a bit confused on exactly what you want to do so you are definitely gonna have to change this up a bit, I just want to use this as a basic example of how to use a list instead.

Comment: New as i am at Java programming, how do i collect/return the even and odds numbers? I´ve tried to compute it but i need to return both the odds and the evens which i am going to use in another method. How do i return all values for both odd and even?

Comment: Well you can try to instead of saying public static List<Integer> make the method a public static List<List> then .add the two lists into a new List<List> then return that.

Comment: like List<List> lists = new List<List>();

Comment: lists.add(evens);

Comment: lists.add(odds);

Comment: return lists;   should do i think

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to return from the function an array of odd numbers and an array of even numbers from user input.
but you are returning only one array which is just an array of the users inputs (with no logical meaning for the conditions in the loop).

from what I know - it is not possible to return 2 arrays, but there are solutions of course. you can return a **class** or a **dictionary**, for example.
if you choose a dictionary it will be something like `Dictionary<string,object>`, and will have 2 items, the string will be "odd" \ "even", and the object will be the matching array of the numbers (`int[]` or `List<int>`). odd numbers array a value of "odd" key, and even numbers array a value of "even" key in the dictionary.

two problems that appear to me here other than that: 
1.) you are trying to use 2 variables that are not defined or even mentioned in the function (**even** and **odd**).
2.) in each condition you wrote **return**. this will exit the loop and function on the first iteration.

hope this was helpfull.